# Contagem regressiva no PLACEHOLDER é possivel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Gostaria de saber primeiro se é possivel isso, e tambem desabilitar o input onde o placeholder se encontra ate terminar a contagem e quando terminar a contagem habilitar novamente? algum esboço? jquery e o mais indicado?

Answer (score 0):

Com jQuery fica muito fácil, olha aqui um exemplo abaixo:

```js
$("#btnClick").click(function(){
  var cont = 10;
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    cont--;
    $("#myInput").attr("disabled", true );
    $("#myInput").attr("placeholder", cont );
    if(cont == 0){
      $("#myInput").attr("disabled", false );
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  },1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="10" />
<button id="btnClick">Go Contagem!</button>
```

Comment: é bem isso mesmo, mais ai no caso o botao dando submit para a funcao, nao dara conflito quando eu adicionar para enviar informacao? e outra coisa quando vc digita algo e clica no contagem regressiva , o jquery nao realiza a contagem denovo.

Comment: O principio é esse ai que mostrei, ai você usa pra sua necessidade, eu coloquei o botão pra facilitar a ver quando inicia a contagem.. Quando digitar algo tem que apagar o texto no click do botão porque placeholder só aparece quando o input tá vazio mesmo